# I want to change ng2-smart-table search placeholder text

Tags: angular, placeholder, nebular, ng2-smart-table

I have tried the following solution but it's not working.
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232701/how-to-update-placeholder-text-in-ng2-smart-table"

```
 settings = {
    actions: { add: false, position: 'right' },

    edit: {
      editButtonContent: '<i class="text-primary nb-edit"></i>',
      saveButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',

    },
    delete: {
      deleteButtonContent: '<i class="text-danger nb-trash"></i>',
      confirmDelete: true,
    },
    columns: {
      organization_name: {
        title: 'Name',
        type: 'string',
      },

      organization_address: {
        title: 'Address',
        type: 'string',
      },
      organization_phone: {
        title: 'Phone',
        type: 'string',
      }
    },
    mode: 'external',

  };
```

my HTML code:

```
   <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="tableRows"
              (edit)="addEdit($event.data.organization_id,$event.data.organization_userid)" (delete)="deleteRes($event.data.organization_id,$event.data.organization_userid)" >
              </ng2-smart-table>
```

Column title is showing as the placeholder but I want to change the placeholder which I am not been able to do.

Comment: Currently, I am using the 1.6.0 version of ng2-smart-table. Please let me know if it supports this feature or not.

Comment: You'd better switch to angular2-smart-table, they have placeholder as an attribute to columns and that's the best fork for ng2-smart-table